# Is there any way in JetBrains Rider to keep the "find" input box between files

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

I'm using JetBrains Rider. Quite often I hit <kbd>Ctrl +F</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd + F</kbd>, actually, on a Mac), type the text I'm looking for. This part works.

Now, almost as often, I'll then switch to a different file, because I want to search in a different file, too. The "find" input box then disappears. Not only that, but if I hit <kbd>Ctrl +F</kbd> again, the input box shows, with the last text I searched for, **in this file**.

That forces me to type again what I'm searching for. This is quite annoying, and very different from what the other IDEs offer.

Is there a setting to adjust this behaviour?

Comment: if I find one page in rider, then F3 on another page it seems to find the same thing

Comment: oh. Hitting F3 searches for the same thing. Nice. Put that as an answer, please!

Answer (score 2):

In jetbrains rider you can use <kbd>F3</kbd> to find the next thing in the search, this will work across files.  So when you switch to another file it will start searching from the cursor for the next match in that file.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not possible.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152119 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress. Another related ticket: [IDEABKL-5260](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5260)

**P.S.** Please note that those tickets are for IDEA platfom. Rider is a bit different beast (still IDEA platform but with many specific changes) and those tickets **may not** be applicable here (unlike PyCharm/PhpStorm/RubyMine/etc that would automatically inherit such platform-wide functionality).

Comment: @Jeffrey 1) If you invoke "Find" in another file, then just press `Arrow Down` and it will select the previously used search term (e.g. from another editor tab). 2) Maybe `Find in Path` (Find in Files) will be a more convenient in case of multiple files? it can search in whole project, specific folder or specific scope (custom set of folders/files .. or predefined set like "Currently opened files etc"). Then you can use "Open in Find Window" button to have all results listed in a separate tool window and navigate between them/see a preview right there.

Comment: FYI I've created a new RIDER specific ticket here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-86763/Keep-Search-Window-Popups-Open